# DEV C++ : No error while compiling any program but it is not running

Tags: c++

All is working fine with DEV C++. Suddenly it stops working. The Program is compiling with no error messages. But when I hit the run button, nothing happens. This is happening with all programs. So there is no issue with the specific program.

This was also happening earlier with me. Then I reinstalled DEV C++ and it worked fine. But after sometimes it started again. I don't want to reinstall it again and again. 
Currently I'm using Windows 10.

Any help will be great. Thank You.

Comment: Description for the [tag:dev]: "The Linux/Unix /dev directory contains the special device files for all the devices. " (see http://superuser.com/tags/dev/info).   This is not the tag you are looking for....

Comment: Are you writing console apps and compiling them as Win32 apps? An EXE compiled for the Win32 subsystem does not create a console window, so if you wrote a console app, you won't see anything. What happens when you try to run the program directly on disk? Don't hit the Run button; go to the folder where your project is stored and actually run the executable itself. See if it does anything. If not, you're probably compiling for the wrong subsystem.

Comment: Same program is running well in DEV C++ and on same system.  Before it start not to run any program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved. It was my avast who is blocking the application to launch. Avast is considering the application as a false positive means as a threat to the system(false).

Avast was wrong it was not a threat for the system. That's why it is a false positive. Then i add an exception(rule) to avast not to scan a particular file/folder. But this is also not working well.